# Uni Test Integration Connection Fail in SpringBoot WebSocket 3.1.2

Tags: spring, unit-testing, websocket, boot

I'm new player Spring boot with Websocket.

I'd like to make websocket tests but connection failed.

I'd like to test following sequence

- power up Application
- connect weboscket

Here is sample code what I tried.

the application run with spring framework 3.1.2 and couldn't find any of integration unit test code.

**WebSocketConfig** :

```
@EnableWebSocket
@Configuration
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class WebSocketConfig implements WebSocketConfigurer {
    @Override
    public void registerWebSocketHandlers(WebSocketHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addHandler(new WebSocketHandler(), "/test")
                .addInterceptors(getHandshakeInterceptor())
                .setAllowedOrigins("*");
    }

    @Bean
    public WebsocketHandshakeInterceptor getHandshakeInterceptor() {
        return new WebsocketHandshakeInterceptor();
    }
}
```

**WebSocketHandler**

```
public class WebSocketHandler extends TextWebSocketHandler {

    @Override
    public void afterConnectionEstablished(WebSocketSession session) throws Exception {
        super.afterConnectionEstablished(session);
    }
}
```

**Test Code :**

```
@EnableWebSocket
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
class DemoApplicationTests {

    @LocalServerPort
    private int port;

    @Test
    void contextLoads() throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException, TimeoutException {
        WebSocketStompClient stompClient = new WebSocketStompClient(new StandardWebSocketClient());
        stompClient.setMessageConverter(new MappingJackson2MessageConverter());

        CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);

        StompSession stompSession = stompClient.connect("ws://localhost:" + port + "/test", new StompSessionHandlerAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void afterConnected(StompSession session, StompHeaders connectedHeaders) {
                latch.countDown();
            }
        }).get(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        assertTrue(latch.await(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS));
        assertTrue(stompSession.isConnected());
    }

}
```

**Exception Log
**

```
java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.timedGet(CompletableFuture.java:1960)
```

That's all what I tried there were not chagned any default setting.

It seems the spring application context not configure about websocket handler like **/test**

Are there setup configure or missing annotation to configure websocket unittest?